# Were the Romans Trojans or Latins?

Tags: ancient-rome

I was reading the ***Aeneid by Virgil*** and it looks like the ***Romans*** allegedly descended from the ***Trojan*** soldier ***Aeneas***. The book then explains how this soldier fathered generations that fathered someone called ***Romulus*** who founded the ***city of Rome***. Since ***Latin*** was the official language used in ancient Rome, I suppose its the ***Latins*** and not the descendants of Aeneas that built the ***Roman Republic***. So what is the true identity of the Romans, descendants of the Trojan warrior or are were they just the natural inhabitants of the ***Latinian*** kingdom just expanding in all directions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to History SE. Does this help? [Ancient Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Rome#Founding_myth). If not not, please edit your question to clarify the problem.

Comment: there are multiple myths on the founding of Rome, which is the closest to the truh?

Comment: i just want to know if they were trojans or latin or both?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founding_of_Rome#Archaeology

Comment: Its because the novel above says the Trojan settlers copulated and had descendants who founded the city of Rome and then Romulus started accepting rejects and other undesirables into his town, so they were a mixture of both?

Comment: [Related](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/48054/17887).

Comment: Please document the research you've already done.    They were Latin by historical [ethnogenisis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ethnogenesis), but were Trojans by myth.   While the myth of Trojan origins can be studied by history, it is not treated as historical fact.

Comment: But the references to roman history in this book is astonishing like Dido predicted Hannibal would avenge what Aeneas did and several other references to pompei and Caesar.

Comment: The Aeneides has been written way after the Cartago wars... so, everybody is good to predict some events that have already happened :)

Comment: Even the birth of Christ from the ***fourth Eclogue***, given Virgil died in 19 BC, some historians argue the ***fourth Eclogue*** predicted the birth of the Messiah.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Aeneid by Virgil is not an historical book, but a mythological one, telling a founding myth of Rome.
It can be considered to have been written "on commission" by Augustus, to legitimize the Julio-Claudian dynasty as descendants of the founders, heroes, and gods of Rome and Troy (as reported from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeneid)).

There are a lot of different [myths about the origin of the founding of Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founding_of_Rome#Founding_myths_and_sources), of which Aeneid is just the most famous.

That said, other than myths, the archaeological discoveries told us that ancient Rome was populated by Latin populations, and are Indo-European people, [migrated from central Europe around 1000 BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latins_(Italic_tribe)).

It must be taken into consideration that the Italic peninsula was the target of many different migrations, and many different populations were present at the time of the founding of Rome (the [Etruscan population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_civilization#Genetic_research) was an autochthonous population of central Italy).

So Rome is most likely to have been founded by locals (Latin - Indo-European) people rather than having a Greek origin.

Comment: I kind of want to buy the Romulus theory, he started the Roman tradition of wearing a helmet with twin plumes

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU mostly unlikely: Romulus and Remus were shepherd, not warriors, and in case of war they were not so organized to wear complex weapon.
There is an [italian tv serie](https://tg24.sky.it/spettacolo/serie-tv/romulus) that can help you visualize

Comment: If you look at the map I posted, the Latins' territory conspicuously follows the outline of the Tiber river (unlike their Italic neighbors, whose territory boundaries look rather blocky, or follow mountain ranges). So it seems likely most of the founding population of Rome was more into farming along that river valley, while their other Latin neighbors were indeed likely more into herding)

Comment: It's not all that certain how "autochthonous" the Etruscans were.

Comment: @Spencer - I think the slightly more conservative language people like to use today is that they were [Paleo-European"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleo-European_languages).

Answer (score 7):

As far as cultural heritage goes, your best bet is almost always linguistics. The linguistics in this case are quite clear. The Romans were Latins.

Latin is an Indo-European language of the [Italic family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_languages). This means the cultural ancestors of the Romans were the [Italic Tribes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_peoples) who migrated into Italy from the north around 1,800 BC.

[image: Breakup of Indo-European]

The Italics themselves seem to have been part of a group of proto-Indo-Europeans (along with the Germanics and the Gauls) who split off from the rest of the Indo-Europeans as a group in about the 3rd Milenium BCE, likely as part of a joint move into the Danube valley. Those 3 started splitting from each other soon after, with the Germanics moving north and the Italics moving south into the Italian peninsula.

After the Italics moved into the interior of the Peninsula, over many generations they split into various sub-groups, with the Latins being the group that founded the city of Rome. Meanwhile (non-Indo-European) Etruscans became the dominant power in the north, while the burgeoning Greek peoples started colonizing the coastal areas in the south. As you can see from this map below, the Latins were in a rather humble position, and in fact Rome was sending tribute to the Etruscans for a lot of its earliest history.

[image: Iron Age Italy Linguistics]

Eventually of course Rome turned the tables on the Etruscans and became the dominant power in the peninsula (on their way to becoming the dominant power in the Mediterranean world). However, coming up from nobodies wasn't considered a very inspiring story back then, which is why a mythology of descent from a noble people with a very old history (Trojans) became the preferred story.

Comment: Interestingly, imperial Britain adopted the Trojan myth: telling a man "You're a Trojan!" was a signifier of courage, virtue and nobility. Still found it in books I read as a young girl.

Comment: ***Coming up from nobodies wasn't so appreciated back then*** to mean that the Aeneid was made up? what about all the prophecies Aeneas was told by his father while in Elysium concerning the future glory of Rome?

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU It's very easy to write prophecies in historical fiction if you as the author live in a time where they have (supposedly) already come to pass.